# List users in memory in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security

Or more specifically, *is it possible*?

We currently have our users in memory using XML configuration. We know of `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`, but unfortunately it's not possible to get all users and `users` map inside `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` is private.

Comment: you need a list of all users, so why don't you query DB using your service layer components? something like `userService.findAll()`

Comment: @essytheostrich unfortunately our users are configured in XML and not in DB

Comment: suppose you are using layered application architecture and you have DAO layer, with an implementation of UserDao which interacts with xml file (e.g UserDaoXmlImpl) you can load them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can actually access that using a bit a jugglery with Java reflection where you can access the properties which are not exposed via public API.
I have used below the [RelectionUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html) from Spring which should be available if you are using Spring ( which you are since it's Spring security).
The key is to get hold of AuthenticationManager via Autowiring and then drill down to the required `Map` containing the user info.

Just to demonstrate I have tested this on Spring Boot App but there should not be any issue if your are not using it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootSecurityInMemoryApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

     @Autowired AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

................................
...............................
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSecurityInMemoryApplication.class, args);
    }

@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {      
        introspectBean(authenticationManager);


    }

public void printUsersMap(Object bean){

        Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.class, "providers");
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        List listOfProviders = (List)ReflectionUtils.getField(field, bean);     
        DaoAuthenticationProvider dao = (DaoAuthenticationProvider)listOfProviders.get(0);
        Field fieldUserDetailService = ReflectionUtils.findField(DaoAuthenticationProvider.class, "userDetailsService");
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(fieldUserDetailService);
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDet = (InMemoryUserDetailsManager)(ReflectionUtils.getField(fieldUserDetailService, dao));
        Field usersMapField = ReflectionUtils.findField(InMemoryUserDetailsManager.class, "users");
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(usersMapField);
        Map map = (Map)ReflectionUtils.getField(usersMapField, userDet);
        System.out.println(map);

    }
```

I have 2 users configured - shailendra and admin. You can see the output of program below. You can get the required info from this map.

{shailendra=org.springframework.security.provisioning.MutableUser@245a060f, admin=org.springframework.security.provisioning.MutableUser@6edaa77a}

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of `ReflectionUtils` until you mentioned it. I'll have a look at that. Anyway, I agree that this is a bit tricky but I'll consider this an option.

Comment: what is bean in method params?